# Result of a query into array C# Metro Apps

Tags: c#, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml

I'm using sqlite. I need to convert sql-query to an array in c# for windows 8 apps.Please, tell me, how can i read row by row the query?
(In Windows Forms i used ExecuteReader(), but in sqlite for windows 8 apps i can find no such method to use)
Thank You!

Comment: using (var db = new SQLite.SQLiteConnection(PathLocalFolderdbs))
            {
                var names = db.CreateCommand("Select namebd from names").ExecuteNonQuery();
     // here i want to make an array from this query
     

                            }

Answer (score 0):

Any code to show ? What have you tried so far ?

EDIT: 
First thank you for the code, it will be easier to "debug" what you have.

db.CreateCommand("Select namebd from names").ExecuteNonQuery() <-- This will never work, as ExecuteNonQuery returns the number of rows that have been changed by your query.

You should use ExecuteQuery instead.

```
SQLiteDataReader reader = db.CreateCommand("Select namebd from names").ExecuteReader();
List<string> list = new List<int>();
using (SqlDataReader reader = reader){
    while (reader.Read())
    {
         list.Add(reader.GetString(0));
    }    
}
return list.ToArray();
```

Comment: using (var db = new SQLite.SQLiteConnection(PathLocalFolderdbs))
            {
                var names = db.CreateCommand("Select namebd from names").ExecuteNonQuery();
     // here i want to make an array from this query
     

                            }

Comment: I don't know, why BUT...
There is no SQLiteDataReader in sqlite for windows 8 c#.:)
I can see nothing like Reader in the methods in sqlite library EXACTLY for windows 8 apps)

THIS IS THE MAIN PROBLEM!